# Unable to Kill Greenlets in Python Script with Ctrl C command

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

When I press `Ctrl+C` the call jumps into `signal_handler` as expected, but the `greenlets` are not getting killed as they continue the process.

```
# signal handler to process after catch ctrl+c command
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    print("Inside Signal Handler")
    gevent.sleep(10)
    print("Signal Handler After sleep")
    gevent.joinall(maingreenlet)
    gevent.killall(maingreenlet,block=True,timeout=10)
    gevent.kill(block=True)
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler) // Catching Ctrl+C

 try:
   maingreenlet = [] // Creating a list of greenlets
   while True:
    for key,profileval in profile.items():
      maingreenlet.append(gevent.spawn(key,profileval)) # appending all grrenlets to list
      gevent.sleep(0)
  except (Error) as e:
    log.exception(e)
    raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason your code is not working is because the variable `maingreenlet` is defined inside the `main` function, and is out of the scope of the `signal_handler` function which tries to access it. Your code should throw an error like this:

`NameError: global name 'maingreenlet' is not defined`

If you were to move the line `maingreenlet = []` into the global scope, i.e. anywhere outside of the two `def` blocks, the `greenlets` should get killed without problem.

Of course that's after you fix the other issues in your code, like using `//` instead of `#` to start the comments, or calling the function `gevent.kill` with the wrong parameter. (you didn't specify your `gevent` version but I assume the current version 1.3.7) Actually this function call is redundant after you call `gevent.killall`.

Learn to use a Python debugger liker [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or [rpdb2](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/winpdb.html) to help you debug your code. It'll save your precious time in the long run.